# Accessing Global variable from app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, global-variables

I am attempting to create a global variable as outlined in the tutorial [here.](http://blog.mettletech.co/wp/blog/ios-global-variables/) Howeer, when I attempt to assign my AppDelegate with the following code, I'm getting an error relating to no declared @interface for 'delegate'

```
AppDelegate = [(RoadSafetyAppAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Basically, i have a string declared in my app delegate which i need to use as a global variable, but i can't access it because of this error.

Can anyone see what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast is in the wrong place. You want:

```
AppDelegate = (RoadSafetyAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

You want to cast the result of the call to `delegate`, not the call to `sharedApplication`.

BTW - it is standard practice to name variables and methods starting with lowercase letters. Only start class names with uppercase letters.

Comment: Thanks for that! maybe you would be able to help with how I'm actually implementing the Global Variable :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240181/displaying-alert-from-app-delegate-before-displaying-alert-from-viewdidload